# Comparison operators in expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following query doesn't work in T-SQL:

```
SELECT Balance < Credit
FROM Accounts
```

with the following error:

```
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 23,Token in error = < ]
```

`Balance`, `Credit` and `Accounts` are all valid table/field names.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Yes that won't work, it doesn't make any sense. I don't see a question here.

Comment: @Bridge Please read my answer to see the answer I was expecting. As an aside, I am used to Jet SQL, where you can use a Boolean expression everywhere.

Comment: I have read your answer. You've edited your question to include an actual question now! It's not entirely obvious what you were trying to do with the original query, but if you've got what you wanted to know, then I guess there's no point asking for clarification :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because T-SQL (both in SQL Server and SQL Server CE) doesn't hava a native `BOOLEAN` data type, and logical expressions can only be used in certain places, like `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried ?

```
SELECT Balance from Accounts
where Balance < Credit
```

Comment: I know I can do that. I wanted to use it in the `SELECT`.